Platypus app returning "cannot execute binary file" after giving it a shell script. Why?
I am creatign an app which I orginally created in Python. I then ran the Pyinstaller command to turn it into a shell script. I then inputed this shell script into Platypus to turn it in to a .app file. I have tried making the app in Pyinstaller, but it has issues too. Below, I have my orginal Python code, the command I ran to create the Pyinstaller script, and a screenshot of the Platypus app setup. As a note: When I run the shell script without making it an app, I recive no errors, and it works as expected.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import json
import logging
import datetime
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='app.log', filemode='w',
                    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

PREFERENCES_FILE = os.path.join(application_path, "user_preferences.json")

def save_preferences(data):
    try:
        with open(PREFERENCES_FILE, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        logging.info("Preferences saved successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to save preferences: {e}")

def load_preferences():
    try:
        if os.path.exists(PREFERENCES_FILE):
            with open(PREFERENCES_FILE, 'r') as f:
                return json.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error reading preferences: {e}")
    return None

def delete_preferences():
    try:
        if os.path.exists(PREFERENCES_FILE):
            os.remove(PREFERENCES_FILE)
            logging.info("Preferences deleted successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to delete preferences: {e}")

def show_schedule(day, preferences):
    schedule = preferences['schedule']
    day_schedule = schedule.get(day, [])
    schedule_text = f"Schedule for {day}:\n"
    for time_range, subject_key in day_schedule:
        subject = preferences['subjects'].get(subject_key, "Free")
        schedule_text += f"{time_range} - {subject}\n"
    schedule_label.config(text=schedule_text)

def setup_preferences():
    def save_and_close():
        subjects = {
            'MESH1': mesh1_var.get(),
            'MESH2': mesh2_var.get(),
            'MESH3': mesh3_var.get(),
            'MESH4': mesh4_var.get(),
            'WL': wl_var.get(),
            'WELLNESS': 'Wellness',
            'ELECTIVE1': elective1_entry.get(),
            'ELECTIVE2': elective2_entry.get(),
            'CLUB': club_entry.get(),
            'GEOMETRY': 'Geometry' if geometry_var.get() else None,
            'RECESS': 'Recess',
            'LUNCH': 'Lunch',
            'ACADEMIC_COACHING': 'Academic Coaching',
            'ADVISORY': 'Advisory'
        }
        wellness_day = wellness_day_var.get()
        preferences = {
            'subjects': subjects,
            'schedule': load_default_schedule(geometry_var.get(), wellness_day)
        }
        save_preferences(preferences)
        setup_root.destroy()
        main_app()

    setup_root = tk.Tk()
    setup_root.title("Setup Preferences")

    mesh_options = ["Math", "English", "Science", "History"]
    wl_options = ["Spanish", "French", "FOL"]
    day_options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']  # Days of the schedule
    mesh1_var, mesh2_var, mesh3_var, mesh4_var, wl_var = tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()
    geometry_var = tk.BooleanVar()
    wellness_day_var = tk.StringVar(value='')

    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH 1:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh1_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH 2:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh2_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH 3:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh3_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select MESH 4:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=mesh4_var, values=mesh_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select WL:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=wl_var, values=wl_options).pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Select Wellness Day:").pack()
    ttk.Combobox(setup_root, textvariable=wellness_day_var, values=day_options).pack()

    ttk.Checkbutton(setup_root, text="Include Geometry", variable=geometry_var).pack()

    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter AM ICE:").pack()
    elective1_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    elective1_entry.pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter PM ICE:").pack()
    elective2_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    elective2_entry.pack()
    ttk.Label(setup_root, text="Enter Club:").pack()
    club_entry = ttk.Entry(setup_root)
    club_entry.pack()

    ttk.Button(setup_root, text="Save and Start", command=save_and_close).pack(pady=10)
    setup_root.mainloop()

def load_default_schedule(include_geometry, wellness_day):
    today = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()  # Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6
    geometry_days = [0, 2, 4]  # Monday, Wednesday, Friday
  
    schedule = {
        'A': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "CLUB"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH1"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH3"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH2"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WL"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH4"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'B': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH2"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH3"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH4"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH1"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'C': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ACADEMIC_COACHING"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH2"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH4"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH1"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WL"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH3"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'D': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH4"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH1"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH3"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH2"), ("2:20-3:10", "ACADEMIC_COACHING")],
        'E': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "MESH1"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH3"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH2"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "WELLNESS"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH4"), ("2:20-3:10", "ELECTIVE2")],
        'F': [("8:10-8:30", "ADVISORY"), ("8:30-9:20", "ELECTIVE1"), ("9:20-10:10", "WL"),
              ("10:10-10:30", "RECESS"), ("10:30-11:20", "MESH2"), ("11:20-12:10", "MESH3"),
              ("12:10-12:40", "LUNCH"), ("12:40-1:30", "MESH4"), ("1:30-2:20", "MESH1"), ("2:20-3:10", "ACADEMIC_COACHING")]
    }
  
    wellness_time_slot = "12:40-1:30"
    for day, activities in schedule.items():
        if day == wellness_day:
            activities = [(time, subject) if subject != "WL" else (time, "WELLNESS") for time, subject in activities]
            schedule[day] = activities
          
    if include_geometry and today in geometry_days:
        geometry_class = ("7:00-8:00", "GEOMETRY")
        for key in schedule.keys():
            schedule[key].insert(0, geometry_class)
          
    return schedule


def main_app():
    preferences = load_preferences()
    if not preferences:
        setup_preferences()
        return

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("School Schedule")

    day_var = tk.StringVar(value='A')
    day_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=day_var, values=list('ABCDEF'))
    day_dropdown.pack(pady=10)

    show_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Show Schedule", command=lambda: show_schedule(day_var.get(), preferences))
    show_button.pack(pady=5)

    reset_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Reset Preferences", command=lambda: [delete_preferences(), root.destroy(), setup_preferences()])
    reset_button.pack(pady=5)

    global schedule_label
    schedule_label = tk.Label(root, text="", justify=tk.LEFT)
    schedule_label.pack(pady=10)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app()
  

pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=/Users/jacob/\ icon.iconset/857457.icns --name="School Schedule" /Users/jacob/School_Schedule_App_v1.1.py

Platypus Screen of Setting Up Shell Script to Create the App
When I try to run the app, the console text box appears and gives me the error:
"​/Users/jacob/Built/School Schedule 1.1.app/Contents/Resources/script: /Users/jacob/Built/School Schedule 1.1.app/Contents/Resources/script: cannot execute binary file"
Why is this, and how do I fix it? If there is any additonal information you need, please let me knwo and I will do my best to give you the most accurate details. Thank you.

Have you tried passing your Python script directly to Platypus, rather than first building an executable via pyinstaller? AFAICT, Platypus can wrap Python files as well as shell scripts.

I wouldn't call describing pyinstaller's output as "shell scripts" accurate. pyinstaller creates an executable that bundles in an entire Python interpreter; those executables can't be interpreted by a shell alone. (They may have a shell prefix that unpacks and executes other content, but if so that would not be a practice that pyinstaller follows on every platform).

Anyhow -- almost all the code you're showing us is GUI wrangling, when your problem has nothing to do with GUIs! Please see [mre] guidelines -- we want the shortest possible code someone can copy, paste, and run without changes to see the same problem themselves.

(one thing it might be necessary to look at is whether you're notarizing the pyinstaller output)

@CharlesDuffy For your first comment, I have tried that. It does open the GUI window, and the window has a title. However, nothing is in this window, and in the console window I have the error: "​2024-04-29 17:23:35.769 Python[20485:697096] WARNING: Secure coding is automatically enabled for restorable state! However, not on all supported macOS versions of this application. Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:." I'm not entirely sure what this means, if you know, let me know. Thanks

@CharlesDuffy I should have been more specific. The shell script I am talking about is when you right-click on the app, and select "Show Package Contents" --> "Contents" --> "MacOS" --> and the shell script inside of there. I don't know exactly what the file does, if it is helpful, I could send the file to you. Thanks.

@CharlesDuffy, I'm not sure exactly how to make this code easier/shorter to execute, it does require you to have Pyinsaller and Platypus to reproduce the error. If you know of a more efficient way to create this error message, please let me know, but this was the best way for me to create it. Thanks

@CharlesDuffy As far as your last comment, how do I do that? Thanks

@JRiggles Sorry, the first comment I made was for you, I didn't mean to tag Charles Duffy. Thanks
